# iOS + Swift, How to access all music files

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in iOS using swift. What I want to do is get all music file on the iPhone storage, just like iTunes does: I want to display titles, albums, as well as play tracks.

I'm new with iOS programming: what iOS framework should I learn and use in order to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't access music seen in iTunes; but you can access to the music stored in App's document folder.

Comment: What do you mean,we can't access music seen in iTunes?

Comment: What I want to do is get all music file in my directory,so that I get music tittle,music album and music can played on my app.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*The  question is a bit unclear (to me at least).*

You are looking to create a kind of music player application ? You want to add your own music (A) or use the music that the user have in his *Music App Library* (B) ?

In the second case, you might be looking for something like this.

Music files are represented by MPMediaItem instances. You could use retrieve them through a MPMediaQuery, for example :

```
// All
let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items
// Or you can filter on various property
// Like the Genre for example here
var query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
let predicateByGenre = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "Rock", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre)
query.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateByGenre)
```

At this point, you have all (or some if you filter) songs included in Music App Library, so you can play them with a `MPMusicPlayerController` after setting a playlist queue :

```
let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems)

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaCollection)

player.play()
```

There is probably the possibility to access somehow the metadata (title, genre, artist, ...) from the songs.

*This probably won't work on simulator.*

Comment: What I want is using/getting all music file that stored on the user iPhone device or we can say the music that listed on user iTunes.Is the method above will work as what I want?

Comment: Thanks for the response,that was very helpful.I'm following step from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-music-library-access--mobile-6188 though

Comment: Thanks for this. Note: use systemMusicPlayer() instead since iPodMusicPlayer() is deprecated in iOS 8.